# Sentinel HASP returns NoApiDylib for 64bit DLL

Tags: c#, 64-bit, sentinel, anycpu, hasp

Since my solution should be buildable for AnyCPU I had to choose the right Hasp DLL during runtime. This works quite nice with the proxy pattern. When I  use the 32bit hasp_net_windows.dll everything works fine and I am able to login to the dongle successfully.

But while using the x64 DLL the hasp.Login(...) returns NoApiDylib. Seems like this is a problem regarding the HASP DLL or the communication to the USB Dongle. But I am not able to narrow it down.

Have you any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try a clean build?  There may be some obj files that did not get compiled when you changed from 32 bit to 64 bit.

Comment: Yes of course, tried it several times. But it just seems that the hasp stuff itself won't work. I might think of some winodws 10 incompatibilities since our sentinel environment is quite old.

Comment: ///////The is probably something different with the encryption mode for the proxy that is different when you use 32 vs 64.  If you use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler you can compare the header in 32 and 64 to see differences.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that in your directory present those files:
1. hasp_windows_XXXXX.dll
2. hasp_windows_x64_XXXXX.dll
3. apidsp_windows.dll
4. apidsp_windows_x64.dll
5. hasp_net_windows.dll